# App and Database UTF-8 encoded but still exception

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I develop a Rails app linked with a Mysql db.

**In rails console**

```
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.config.encoding
=> "utf-8"
```

**My database**

I use Scalingo for deployment (kind of Heroku), my database.yml looks:

```
"production"=>{"adapter"=>"mysql", "database"=>"****", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>10000, "encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"****", "password"=>"<password>", "port"=>30324, "host"=>"****"}}
```

My app and my DB are well configured but on write of name: 'é' on db for example it returns:

```
=> #<Node id: 21, name: "\xC3\xA9", created_at: "2015-05-18 06:43:29", updated_at: "2015-05-18 06:43:29">
```

How can be this problem fixed?

**SOLUTION**

replace gem mysql with mysql2 and also the adapter to mysql2

Comment: What's the exception?  What is the result of node.name.encoding? Do you have "encoding: utf8" inside config/database.yml?

Comment: Exception: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8.
node.name.encoding => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>.
Yes if have fill my .yml with "encoding: utf8"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up database.yml by define utf-8 of encoding

```
development:
        adapter: mysql
        encoding: utf8
        database: my_international_db
        username: user
        password: password
        socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Now also check your conf file of mysql

in /etc/mysql/my.conf

```
...
[client]

default-character-set=utf8

...
[mysqld]

default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
default-collation=utf8_unicode_ci
...
```

If the above are there then no need to do anything. If you change anything on it then restart mysql server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Please let me know

Comment: This file is good. It means that my app is not well configured?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is returning you UTF-8 encoded data, but the mysql activerecord adapter is not correctly setting the encoding for the strings.  ASCII-8BIT just means a byte strings.

I'm guessing you are using the "mysql" adapter.  Try using the more modern "mysql2" adapter.  To do this add activerecord-mysql2-adapter to you Gemfile, and change your database.yml file so that the new adapter is used:

```
"adapter"=>"mysql2"
```

Comment: I tried with the gem but it did not fixed my issue. Actually if I try Node.new(name: 'my_name').encoding it returns UTF-8, it is only on save that it save in ASCII

Comment: can you edit the question and show your database.yml (without passwords)?

Comment: as well as installing the gem you need to change the "adapter" value in database.yml. i've updated this answer, any luck?